# find the average of a student

Tags: statistics, average

Five students in a closed room want to find average of their exam scores without revealing their personal score to each other. How can they do it? Hint: they can write something on paper and pass it, but nobody be able should see any score at all.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  A adds some large "random" number to his score and passes B the sum, then....

Comment: If each adds a large random number, and there are only five of them, all you get in the end is noise.

Comment: And if you add a small random number, you don't hide your own score.

Comment: @Igor: Only one ‘random’ number, the one added by the first student, is needed.

Comment: @IgorRivin:  both true.  We were not asked to prevent anybody learning another score by asking about the papers others saw, which would complicate things.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ah, so you mean, the first student adds large random number, and in the end subtracts it. Yes, that works...